# Having problems nesting where clausing when querying the Database - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm having a problem querying the database.

My database is as follows:

Table Orders:

- ordernumber
- secondordernumber
- deleted
- created_at
- user_id

  - Table users:
  - username
  - dealername

I've allready made the model relations from orders to users.

```
public function user(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\User','id','user_id');
}
```

How i am constructing my Query:

```
$query = Order::query();

$query->where('deleted', 0);

$fields = array('user' => ['username','dealername'], 'ordernumber', 'ordernumber_second');

foreach ($fields as $relation => $field) {
    if (is_array($field)){
        $query->whereHas($relation, function ($q) use ($field, $searchquery) {
            $q->where(function ($q) use ($field, $searchquery) {
                foreach ($field as $relatedField){
                    $q->orWhere($relatedField, 'like', "%{$searchquery}%");
                } 
            });
        });
    } else {
        $query->orWhere($field, 'like', "%{$searchquery}%");
    }
}


$orders = $query->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();

// return view ETC
```

This works and all, the only this that is not working is the where clause:

`$query->where('deleted', 0);`

Is not working properly, the query is returning all records even if deleted is true..

It probably has something to do with the orWhere earlier on but i can't figure it out.

What i tried:

- putting the `where('deleted' , 0);` on other places
- Nesting the `$query` inside the else

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You might want to output the generated SQL for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at first, I think the better relation would be as below

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
}
```

now in query you may rewrite the code as

```
        $fields = array('user' => ['username','dealername'], 'ordernumber', 'ordernumber_second');

    Order::where(function($query) use ($searchquery, $fields) {
        foreach ($fields as $relation => $field) {
            if (is_array($field)){
                $query->whereHas($relation, function ($q) use ($field, $searchquery) {
                    $q->where(function ($q) use ($field, $searchquery) {
                        foreach ($field as $relatedField){
                            $q->orWhere($relatedField, 'like', "%{$searchquery}%");
                        }
                    });
                });
            } else {
                $query->orWhere($field, 'like', "%{$searchquery}%");
            }
        }
    })->where('deleted', 0)
```

Comment: also by default, the column name will be `deleted_at` if your using soft-deletes